# How to replace characters based on variables in a list using regex sub

Tags: python-3.x, regex, lambda, regex-group

Is it possible to insert different values in a string based on the same matching pattern by using a list to specify the values to insert? I'm using python 3 and re.sub.

Here is what a mean:

```
line = "Float: __, string: __"
values = ["float", "string"]

newLine = re.sub('(_+)([.]_+)?',
    (lambda m:
    f'%'
    f'{len(m.group(1))}'
    f'{"." if values == "float" else ""}'
    f'{(len(m.group(2) or ".")-1) if values == "float" else ""}'
    f'{"f" if values == "float" else "s"}'),
    line)

print(newLine)
```

Expected result:

```
Float: %2.0f, string: %2s
```

Actual result:

```
Float: %2s, string: %2s
```

Is it posssible to loop through the values list in order to get the correct result (this is not working and I get a TypeError)? Something like:

```
newLine = re.sub('(_+)([.]_+)?',
    ((lambda m:
    f'%'
    f'{len(m.group(1))}'
    f'{"." if v == "float" else ""}'
    f'{(len(m.group(2) or ".")-1) if v == "float" else ""}'
    f'{"f" if v == "float" else "s"}') for v in values),
    line)
```

**Edit 1**
The values list and the amount of matching patterns are always of same length.

Comment: Does it mean the number of `values` will always match the number of matches?

Comment: Yes, they will always match in length

Comment: Then the answer below should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot loop like this inside the `repl` argument, but you can define a counter and pass it to the `repl` function:

```py
import re

line = "Float: __, string: __"
values = ["float", "string"]
obj = lambda:None
obj.i = -1

def repl(m, count, values):
    count.i += 1
    return f'%{len(m.group(1))}{"." if values[count.i] == "float" else ""}{(len(m.group(2) or ".")-1) if values[count.i] == "float" else ""}{"f" if values[count.i] == "float" else "s"}'

newLine = re.sub(r'(_+)(\._+)?',
    lambda m: repl(m, obj, values),
    line)

print(newLine)      
## => Float: %2.0f, string: %2s
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/j7rwU7).

Here, an `obj` object is declared, and its `i` property is initialized with `-1`. Then, inside the `repl` function, its value is incremented and used as the index of the `values` list.

Note that this approach works only if the number of matches equals the amount of items in the `values` list.

Comment: @jrn6270 Did it finally work or do you need to adjust anything?

Comment: Yeah, it works, but I don't fully understand how it is working. `i` is set to -1 because then the loop in the `repl` starts at index 0, right? And the `count` parameter is the `obj`, right? Should it be called obj then?

Comment: @jrn6270 You may call the object as you want. `obj` is not a must, you may use your imagination. `count` is the argument to `repl` function. Name as you please. `i` is set to `-1` intially because it is incremented at the start of the `repl` function body so that `0` is used the index when the first match is found, and so on.